# Visual Studio slows to show documentation of objects and methods from imported classes in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When i'm with the mouse above some imported objects and methods in python, sometimes, VSCode automatically shows fast the documentation, but there are times that it's slow, and other that it keeps loading and take a big amouth of time to load. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the new [Pylance extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) as it's rather fast for this sort of thing.